# Run ng-repeat on-click (when ng-show is true)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that is populating with `ng-repeat`. Table has 100 rows, if you click on any row new table will show up, (with `ng-show`) with more deep description of the product. But `ng-repeat` is slow and generating 101 table on-load of the page, and this is slowing down the performance of my web-app. Is there a way, using angular (without external libraries), to run `ng-repeat` only when user clicks on the some row (`ng-show` is true)?

NOTE: Every hidden table is unique.

Here is my html table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="car in sortedCarList" ng-click="showTable(car)">
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.review}}</td>
        <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
        <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
        <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="modelRow.activeRow==car.name && showDetails && car.allReviews.length!=0" class="hidden-table">
        <td colspan="6">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Reviews</th>
                        <th>Rating <span class="fiveStar">/5</span></th>
                        <th>Recommended</th>
                        <th>Reliability Rating</th>
                        <th>Performance Rating</th>
                        <th>Running Costs Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="rev in car.allReviews">
                    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ng-if` rather than `ng-show` to toggle the nested tables. This should delay any `ng-repeat` in the nested table to happen until it's shown.

Comment: Looks like everything working, and performance is much better!